# Paypal sandBox transaction value store database?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I  am Currently using Paypal in my site.Now checking in Paypal Sandbox account. I have Created test account in Sandbox.its my code using PHP with MySQL. After Sandbox Transaction i have store IPN data in to My local Database? Previously its working code Now not Working...

```
   <?php

class paypal_class {

   var $last_error;                 // holds the last error encountered
   var $ipn_log;                    // bool: log IPN results to text file?
   var $ipn_log_file;               // filename of the IPN log
   var $ipn_response;               // holds the IPN response from paypal   
   var $ipn_data = array();         // array contains the POST values for IPN
   var $fields = array();           // array holds the fields to submit to paypal

   function paypal_class() {

     // initialization constructor.  Called when class is created.
     $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
      //$this->paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
      $this->last_error = '';
      $this->ipn_log_file = '.ipn_results.log';
      $this->ipn_log = true; 
      $this->ipn_response = '';
      $this->add_field('rm','2');           // Return method = POST
      $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick'); 
   }

   function add_field($field, $value) {
      $this->fields["$field"] = $value;
   }

   function submit_paypal_post() {
      echo "<html>\n";
      echo "<head><title>Processing Payment...</title></head>\n";
      echo "<body onLoad=\"document.forms['paypal_form'].submit();\">\n";
      echo "<center><h2>Please wait, your order is being processed and you";
      echo " will be redirected to the paypal website.</h2></center>\n";
      echo "<form method=\"post\" name=\"paypal_form\" ";
      echo "action=\"".$this->paypal_url."\">\n";

      foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value) {
         echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\"/>\n";
      }
      echo "<center><br/><br/>If you are not automatically redirected to ";
      echo "paypal within 5 seconds...<br/><br/>\n";
      echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Click Here\"></center>\n";
      echo "</form>\n";
      echo "</body></html>\n";

   }

   function validate_ipn() {
      // parse the paypal URL
      $url_parsed=parse_url($this->paypal_url);        
      $post_string="cmd=_notify-validate"; 
      foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) { 
         $this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;

       // $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)).'&'; 
        $post_string .= '&' . $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value));
      }

     // $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command

      // open the connection to paypal
      $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed[host],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30); 
      if(!$fp) {
         // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
         // will be in the log.
         $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errnum: $errstr";
         $this->log_ipn_results(false);       
         return false;
      } else { 
         // Post the data back to paypal
         fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n"); 

         // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
         while(!feof($fp)) { 
            $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
         } 

         fclose($fp); // close connection
      }

      if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response)) {
         // Valid IPN transaction.
         $this->log_ipn_results(true);
         return true;       
      } else {
         // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the log for details.
         $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
         $this->log_ipn_results(false);   
         return false;
      }
   }

   function log_ipn_results($success) {

      if (!$this->ipn_log) return;  // is logging turned off?

      // Timestamp
      $text = '['.date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '; 

      // Success or failure being logged?
      if ($success) $text .= "SUCCESS!\n";
      else $text .= 'FAIL: '.$this->last_error."\n";

      // Log the POST variables
      $text .= "IPN POST Vars from Paypal:\n";
      foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key=>$value) {
         $text .= "$key=$value, ";
      }

      // Log the response from the paypal server
      $text .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n ".$this->ipn_response;

      // Write to log
      $fp=fopen($this->ipn_log_file,'a');
      fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n"); 

      fclose($fp);  // close file
   }

   function dump_fields() {
      echo "<h3>paypal_class->dump_fields() Output:</h3>";
      echo "<table width=\"95%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">
            <tr>
               <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Field Name</font></b></td>
               <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Value</font></b></td>
            </tr>"; 

      ksort($this->fields);
      foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) {
         echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>".urldecode($value)."&nbsp;</td></tr>";
      }
      echo "</table><br>"; 
   }
}
```

Paypal.php:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Abaceu/lms/conf.php');
require_once('LMS_functions.php');
require_once('paypal.class.php');  // include the class file
//$email = "behavior.solutions.training@gmail.com";

$email = "pixel.thennarasu@gmail.com"; //for testing in sandbox  paypal

$p = new paypal_class;             // initiate an instance of the class
$p->paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';   // testing paypal url
//$p->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';     // paypal url
// setup a variable for this script (ie: 'http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal.php')
$this_script = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// if there is not action variable, set the default action of 'process'
if (empty($_GET['action'])) 
{
    $_GET['action'] = 'process';  
}

$cid=$_POST['courseid'];
switch ($_GET['action']) 
{
   case 'process':      // Process and order...
      $p->add_field('business', $email);
      $p->add_field('return', $this_script.'?action=success');
      $p->add_field('cancel_return', $this_script.'?action=cancel');
      $p->add_field('notify_url', $this_script.'?action=ipn');
      $p->add_field('item_number',$cid);   //June04,2010 courseid,coursename were added to insert second course
      $p->add_field('item_name',$_POST['coursename']);
      $p->add_field('amount', '50.00');
      $p->submit_paypal_post(); // submit the fields to paypal
      //$p->dump_fields();      // for debugging, output a table of all the fields
      break;
   case 'success':      // Order was successful...
      /
      include("thank_you.php");
      break;
   case 'cancel':       // Order was canceled...
      // The order was canceled before being completed.
      echo "<html><head><title>Canceled</title></head><body><h3>The order was canceled.</h3>";
      echo "</body></html>";
      break;
   case 'ipn':          // Paypal is calling page for IPN validation...
      if ($p->validate_ipn()) 
      {
         // For this example, we'll just email ourselves ALL the data.
         $subject = 'Instant Payment Notification - Recieved Payment';
         $to = $email;    //  your email
         $body =  "An instant payment notification was successfully recieved\n";
         $body .= "from ".$p->ipn_data['payer_email']." on ".date('m/d/Y');
         $body .= " at ".date('g:i A')."\n\nDetails:\n";

         foreach ($p->ipn_data as $key => $value) { $body .= "\n$key: $value"; }

         mail($to, $subject, $body);

          //code to instant message after payment written on July 22,2010 as per client request
         $subject1 = 'Instant message for Course Account information';
         $toaddress = $p->ipn_data['payer_email'];    //  your email

         $body1 =  "Thank you very much for your course purchase from ABACEU.COM! You will get the login information shortly. Sometimes It can take several hours depending on the processing speed of the Paypal server \n\n";
         $body1 .= "THIS IS AN AUTOMATED MESSAGE FROM ABACEU.COM\n\n";
         $body1 .= "\n".date('m/d/Y');
         $headers1 = "From: abaceu@abaceu.com" . "\r\n"."CC: behavior.solutions.training@gmail.com";
         mail($toaddress, $subject1, $body1, $headers1);
        // update_LMS( $p->ipn_data ,$dir_usercourselist);
         update_LMS( $p->ipn_data ,$dir_usercourselist, $cid);  //June04,2010 : For inserting new course
    } 
    break;
}
?>
```

Any mistake my code. Please Let me know? Information not stored in database